# How can I delete blank lines in a file?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, tr

I've got a .txt file like this:

[image]

I want to get it like this:

[image]

I'm thinking I need to replace `/(beginning of line)(new line character)/`.

Comment: `grep -v '^$'` ?

Comment: Also see [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Why are you trying to reopen the question without changing its contents, especially considering it already has an answer **and** it's a duplicate?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, what? I didn't try to reopen it.

Comment: Maybe it got a reopen request because of a minor change you did to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't post pictures of text; copy and paste from the terminal into the question.

There are several ways to filter out blank lines.  Two of the simplest would be as follows.

With `grep`:

```
grep -v '^$' /path/to/input > /path/to/output
```

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^$/d' /path/to/input > /path/to/output
sed --in-place '/^$/d' /path/to/input # modify the file rather than creating a new one
```